# How to save after excluding specific parts after CopyFromScreen

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing C# Winform program.

However, it is having a hard time creating functions.

I create a simple code for the screenshot using `CopyFromScreen`.

here is my base code :

```
private void CaptureImage(string _path)
{
      //FHD
      int _refX = 0;
      int _refY = 0;
      int _imgW = 1920;
      int _imgH = 1080;

      string Filepath = _path;

      if (Filepath != string.Empty)
      {
          using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)_imgW, (int)_imgH))
          {
              using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
              {
                  g.CopyFromScreen(_refX, _refY, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
              }

              bitmap.Save(Filepath, ImageFormat.Png);
          }
      }
}
```

And the area should be excluded by `the rectangle` size of `1280x720` in the center of the screen.

I tried many ways, but I couldn't find a way to save the `the rectangle` because it was completely deleted.

How do I save parts `except the rectangle`?

++ https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDntH.jpg

I only need the black area.

Comment: Draw a rectangle of the needed size at the needed position? The graphics object you already have has methods for that.

Comment: I think any side will be fine..